# Vue-CLI, .NET Core 3.1 Razor Pages and HMR

Tags: vue.js, asp.net-core, .net-core

With the depreciation of `UseWebpackDevMiddleware` in .NET Core 3.1 and it's pending removal entirely in .NET 5, I am currently at a loss for how I can replicate my current workflow.

Currently:

I remove the HMR provided by the Vue-CLI and replace it with the functionality provided by the above middleware, I do this primarily because I need to inject some state into the Vue app when it loads and this is achieved via the Razor page which serializes some data into it from the page model.

---

I know I can remove the HTML file generation using the `vue.config.js` file and I can also use the `vue build --watch` to get the rebundling of the files as they are being worked on but the last part of the puzzle is to restore the HMR functionality.

I do not want to use the `UseSpaProxy` as that would send me through to the Vue CLI index.html page, bypassing the Razor page.

I have also tried the Parcel Bundler which does get me part of the way along, but then more advanced features like option chaining seem to have issues at the moment, so if I can stick to the Vue CLI then that would solve everything.

Comment: Hey Jak did you happen to find a solution for this? I have a very similar concern

Comment: Hey @JeffBeltran I am still searching unfortunately, I have found many ways to replace the Index.html file with a Razor page that is then injected with the Webpack files, but since it is served from memory during development, I cannot get my server-side injected state. Trying to search for SSR solutions as well is proving just as fruitless :(

Comment: @JakHammond Have you found a solution now? :)

Comment: At the moment I am using the normal SPA pipeline approach, with some values added to index.html in a JSON object and then, since we use Azure DevOps, I have a task that changes those values based on the environment we are deploying into. There is then a authenticated API endpoint I've added that lazily loads the rest of the settings. Sadly I've not found a way to use Razor pages directly unless you use a fork of the old WebpackDevMiddleware that is kicking around on GitHub,